# Create folder with WMI with alternate credentials

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script to create a folder on a remote computer with WMI. But I need to run this with alternate credentials. Normally I would just add `-credential $cred` to the command but I don't know where to put it in this case.

```
$computer = "COMPUTERNAME" # add the computername where the folder needs to bee created
$pathname = "PATHNAME"     # add the path and foldername to be added

# Start local process with help of WMI
$p = [WMIClass]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Process" 
$p.Create("cmd.exe /c md $pathname")  # run CMD to execute the action
```

Comment: Why not use ``invoke-command``?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: So this means i would invoke-command -credential $cred and then the part from [WMIClass]?

Comment: You shouldn’t even need to use WMIClass. 

``invoke-command $Computer -credentials $cred -ScriptBlock{New-Item -itemtype Directory -path $path}``

Comment: It seems like WinRM should be allowed before this works. The reason i need WMI is that only this is allowed by our organization. As you might discovered Powershell is still quite unknow for me.

Comment: Have a look at `Get-CimInstance` parameter `-CimSession`.

Comment: @zett42 i'm sorry i don't know how that works. I'm not really into powershell so i have a hard time understanding this.

Comment: I've created something but it makes no sense can anyone make something out if this?
$CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -credential $cred 
Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -Classname Win32_Process 
Create("cmd.exe /c md $pathname")  # run CMD to execute the action

Comment: You need to save CIM instance in variable: `$p = Get-CimInstance -CimSession $CimSession -Classname Win32_Process; $p.Create("cmd.exe /c md $pathname")`. Make sure to clean up using `Remove-Cim*` cmdlets.